# SMTP PRO installed and activated properly but

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, smtp

Magento sends mails only on thunderbird email, and probably through native magento mail function. About a month ago it was working fine, and then for some unknown reason it stopped. Worth to say there was some malware sending spam through our ip, and ip got blacklisted on two lists, it got removed from one, I'm waiting for it to be removed from the second blacklist, is it possible that the ip is blacklisted on some google blacklist, and for that reason I can't receive it on gmail, outlook etc. Although I'm not sure if that would be the case because the mail is being sent through mailto function and not smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you were on a blacklist, it's possible that you're still listed and your email is being filtered as a result.

I'd check the IP address of the server using a free service like this one:
https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

If you're listed, I'd go through the removal procedures.

Second, I'd recommend that your IP address have a reverse DNS record that matches the domain name of your website; this needs to be done from your hosting company's side of things (not your DNS zone file)

Third, make sure you have an SPF record for your DNS zone file that gives the server (or your SMTP server) authoritative permission to send on behalf of your domain.

Fourth, make sure that the email address in the From address line comes from your domain name.  If you're trying to send through hotmail, yahoo or gmail, it's not going to get through very well.

Fifth, my suggestion would be to use a service like Send Grid to send your transactional emails - you'll use them as your SMTP gateway.  They have a free tier, and I use them for my wife's site and a few others.

I hope this helps!